# Access VBA function While...Wend or Do ...Loop

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on a function for my access database that fills in a form field in my task form automatically based on the data entered in products forms.

```
    Function IsProductReceived(varID As Variant) As String

    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngTOID As Long
    Dim strReceiveDate As Date
    Dim bAcceptable As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If IsNull(varID) Then
      IsProductReceived = "TBD"
    Else
        lngTOID = varID
        strSQL = "SELECT tblProduct.TaskID, tblProduct.Received, tblProduct.Acceptable FROM tblProduct WHERE tblProduct.TaskID = " & lngTOID

       rst.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
    IsProductReceived = "TBD"
    Exit Function
     Else
     While rst.EOF = False

     If rst![Received] <> "" Then
        strReceiveDate = rst![Received]
        bAcceptable = rst![Acceptable]
        If IsDate(strReceiveDate) Then
            If bAcceptable = False Then
                IsProductReceived = "YES/NOT ACCEPTED"
            Else
                IsProductReceived = "YES/ACCEPTED"
            End If
        Else
            IsProductReceived = "NO"
        End If
    Else
        IsProductReceived = "NO"
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
    Wend
End If


rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End If
 Exit Function


    ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Err.Clear
If rst.State = adStateOpen Then
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End If
End Function
```

There is often more that one product forms related to the task form and products are received at different times. I want the "IsProductReceived = "no" to remain on the task form until ALL products related to the task are received.

This code seems to be working as long as the first product has not been received. I can seem to figure out how to make it remain "no" until all products are received.

I currently am using a while/wend, I have attempted a Do/loop but am still not having satisfactory results. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question, but have you tried stepping through the code to understand *why* it's not acting the way you expect it should?  If so, has that lent any insight?

Comment: If there are 5 products, 4 of them received and and 2 of them accepted, what would the output of your function be? ("No", I presume). What if all 5 are received and only 2 accepted?

Comment: @Tomalak - correct on 1st assumption - second question the field would be "Yes/Not Accepted"

Comment: @Johnny Bones I don't know how to step through the code :-(

Comment: @pja - In the left margin, right next to the line that reads "While rst.EOF = False", if you click there you should see a red dot appear.  This is a "break point".  It will pause the code and jump to the VBA window.  To "step through" the code, hit the F8 key.  Each time you press it, it will process one line of code.  This will allow you to see what it's doing, whether it's jumping over code it shouldn't be, or ending code prematurely.  You **really, really** need to get familiar with this window if you're going to be successful with Access or VBA.

Comment: @JohnnyBones thank you! I am going to a VBA class in May but need this corrected prior to that. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Function IsProductReceived(TaskID) As String
    Dim product As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    Dim countAll As Integer
    Dim countReceived As Integer
    Dim countAccepted As Integer

    IsProductReceived = "TBD"

    If Not IsNumeric(TaskID) Then Exit Function

    sql = "SELECT Received, Acceptable FROM tblProduct WHERE TaskID = " & TaskID
    product.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    While Not product.EOF
        countAll = countAll + 1
        If IsDate(product!Received) Then countReceived = countReceived + 1
        If product!Acceptable Then countAccepted = countAccepted + 1
        product.MoveNext
    Wend

    product.Close

    If countAll = 0 Then
        IsProductReceived = "No"
    ElseIf countAll = countAccepted Then
        IsProductReceived = "YES/ACCEPTED"
    ElseIf countAll = countReceived Then
        IsProductReceived = "YES/NOT ACCEPTED"
    Else
        IsProductReceived = "No"
    End If
End Function
```

A few notes:

- Indent your code better.
- Drop the faux Hungarian notation, use descriptive variable names.
- Avoid deep nesting, especially when it comes to determining the return value.
- Check parameters and exit early if the check fails. This removes nesting depth from the function.
- Avoid `Variant` parameter types unless the function *must* deal with different data types. Here an `Integer` or `Long` type would probably be a better fit. (Using a typed function parameter removes the need for a type check entirely.)
- `While x = False` is an antipattern. Use `While Not x`.
- No need to save recordset fields in local variables first. Just use them directly.
- Avoid building SQL from string concatenation. After an `IsNumeric()` check the above is probably okay, but [you really should use parameterized queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200190).

Answer (score 0):

The issue I'm seeing with your code is that you're getting a record set from a table, looping through the set and testing "Recieved" and then assigning a return value for your function after each test. Effectively, you're just returning the value of the very last record in the recordset. Perhaps instead of setting the value of `isProductRecieved` inside the While loop, set a bool value to false whenever you encounter a product that hasn't been recieved and then set the return value of the function after the loop:

```
Dim receive As Boolean
Dim accept As Boolean
receive = True
accept = False

If rst![Received] <> "" Then
        strReceiveDate = rst![Received]
        bAcceptable = rst![Acceptable]
        If IsDate(strReceiveDate) Then
            If bAcceptable = False Then
                accept = False
            Else
                accept = True
            End If
        Else
            receive = False
        End If
    Else
        receive = False
    End If
```

So now, if "receive" makes it all the way to the end of your while loop, you know that each product is received but if any product was not received it would be set to false. You could also build a short circuit in there to make it a tiny bit faster.